# Nightwatch.js loop through table

Tags: javascript, html, testing, nightwatch.js, system-testing

I am using Nightwatch.js to write some System Tests. Now I want to loop through all elements of a table and check their values. How can I do this with Nightwatch.js? The table has a `<tbody>` element containing several rows `<tr>`. Every row has several columns `<td>`. I want to get the values of every first `<td>` element in every row.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469623/nightwatchjs-elements-returning-string-and-not-objects/30941223#30941223).  This talks a bit about how you can use the selenium WebElements to navigate through the tree then check the value of each.

It's a bit goofy; but essentially you'll want to write a custom command which you can do through the nightwatch.js [custom commands](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands) that navigates through the tree checking the values you're looking to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment but use xpath `//table[@name="table_name"]/tbody/tr/td[1]` in xpath selector to the linked question that Petrogad mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I wanted to iterate a table.  More specifically, I wanted to iterate over the TRs, and then in the context of each TR, iterate over the TDs.

I found my answer here, as posted by kunal_bohra: [NightWatch.js - get a list of child WebElements based on relative css locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987433/nightwatch-js-get-a-list-of-child-webelements-based-on-relative-css-locator)